# Redirect results in GET followed by POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, http, redirect

I have a web page where the functioning is split between the main script that displays the content, and a separate webutil.php script that implements all the actions.  The Logout button on the page is pretty simple:

```
<a href="webutil.php?op=logout" class="signout"><span>Logout</span></a>
```

The logout operation in the webutil clears the session variables that contain the login information, calls `session_destroy()`, and then sends a redirect to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, so that the original page is redisplayed.

I use this redirect-back for all the operations on the page, and it works pretty well. But in this case I've noticed a strange thing.  The browser sends a GET for the original page, immediately followed by a POST for the same page.  Since the page doesn't do any form processing of its own, this is mostly innocuous. But if you click the browser's Refresh button, it pops up the warning that you're going to resubmit a form.

I've tried Chrome/FF on a Mac and IE 9 on Windows, and they all demonstrate the problem. I've seen questions about POST followed by GET, but I haven't been able to find this situation.

I've tried to narrow this down to a simple test case that reproduces the problem, but I haven't been able to, so I can't provide a fiddle. You can try the full page at http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php; login with username "test", password "test".  It makes use of jQuery, jQuery UI, and several plugins.
I realize that I'm not giving you much to go on; if you can't figure out the actual problem, I'd appreciate suggestions on how to track it down using Developer Tools.  Is there a way to set a breakpoint when the browser sends a POST, so I can see the context?

Don't bother telling me that the right way to do this page is with AJAX, I know that. I started with an old, non-interactive page, and I added all the interactions incrementally.  I didn't want to rewrite it from scratch to make it use AJAX. Maybe one of these days I'll have the time I need to redo it, but for now I'm continuing with the spaghetti code I have.

Comment: What kind of redirect? `301`, `302`, `303`... ?

Comment: I just do `header("Location: $referer")` in the PHP script, which results in a 302.

Comment: It might be some whitespace in your PHP file messing up the request...?

Comment: The body is empty, it just sends a header containing the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that happening in your scripts; it's not a HTTP issue.  Redirects will result in requests issued with the same method (307/308) or `GET` (302/303).  A `GET` that is redirected will never turn into a `POST`; therefore your problem has nothing to do with the redirect in your logout script.

In your case, schedule-so.php appears to have some kind of timezone detection code.  Here's what happens:

First log out.

```
GET http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/webutil.php?op=logout HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.bridgebase.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.56 Safari/537.4
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ub7ov6vvsrrpgq0g7cdoieqne3
```

This results in the expected redirect.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 23:00:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.3-6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php#

0
```

The browser `GET`s sechedule-so.php.

```
GET http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.bridgebase.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.56 Safari/537.4
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ub7ov6vvsrrpgq0g7cdoieqne3
```

Then schedule-so.php responds with a form that is auto-submitted.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 23:00:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.3-6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: private
Content-Length: 989

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function get_tz()
    {
      var now = new Date()
      document.tz_form.offset.value = now.getTimezoneOffset()
      document.tz_form.submit()
    }
  </script>
  <object><noscript>
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Javascript support is needed for this page (to get your local timezone).<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Your browser either has no Javascript support,
 or has such support disabled.<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  As an alternative, click <a href="http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php?offset=0">here</a> to continue.<br />
  All times will be GMT.</p>  </noscript></object>
</head>
  <body onload='get_tz()'>
   <form name="tz_form" action="/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php" method="post">
      <input type='hidden' name='offset' />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

...and `onload`, JavaScript causes the form to submit, which is where the `POST` comes from.

```
POST http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.bridgebase.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 10
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://dev.bridgebase.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.56 Safari/537.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/new_vugraph/schedule-so.php
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: PHPSESSID=ub7ov6vvsrrpgq0g7cdoieqne3

offset=240
```

Finally landing on the schedule page.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 23:00:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.3-6
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: private
Content-Length: 35892

...
```

So you need to look for `get_tz()` in schedule-so.php and find out why that gets sent to the browser.  My guess is that the user's timezone is stored in session (which gets nuked during logout).

For better insight into what's happening in your HTTP requests, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Forgot all about that timezone stuff (part of the original code that predated me), which is saved in the session. I think I'll change my logout script to just kill the authentication variables, but not nuke the session.